# Firebase $remove() confused about using ref.key() or $id

Tags: firebase, angularfire

I am building a very simple edit/delete function for a list of posts and got the update function working with:

```
    $scope.update = function() {
      var fb = new Firebase("https://mydb.firebaseio.com/Posts/" + $scope.postToUpdate.$id);
      var article = $firebaseObject(fb);
      article.Title = $scope.postToUpdate.Title;
      article.Intro = $scope.postToUpdate.Intro;
      article.Body = $scope.postToUpdate.Body;
      article.$save().then(function(ref) {
          console.log($scope.postToUpdate.Title);
        }, function(error) {
        console.log("Error:", error);
    });
}
```

I assumed that the delete function would be almost identical i.e.

```
$scope.deletePost = function() {
        var fb = new Firebase("https://mydb.firebaseio.com/Posts/" + $scope.postToDelete.$id);
        var article = $firebaseObject(fb);
        $scope.postToDelete = article;
        article.$remove().then(function(ref) {
            console.log("removed:" + $scope.postToDelete.Title);
        }, function(error) {
            console.log("Error:", error);
        });
    }
```

button: `<button type="button"  ng-click="deletePost()">Delete</button>`

But nothing happens. I tried the verion with the firebase ref_key instead but this still has not worked

```
    $scope.deletePost = function() {
        var fb = new Firebase("https://mydb.firebaseio.com/Posts/" + id);
        var id = ref.key();
        var article = $firebaseObject(fb);
        $scope.postToDelete = article;

    article.$remove.then(function(ref) {
        console.log("removed:" + $scope.postToDelete.Title);
    }, function(error) {
        console.log("Error:", error);
    });
}
```

I have been reading through some of the threads and wondering if article should be an array in order to delete the entire object? How do I target the specific item in order to delete it?

FIXED WITH: `article.$remove(article).then(function(ref)` But I still do not understand when to use ref.key() or $id (firebase/angularfire?)

Comment: It's very unclear what you're asking. In your third block of code, you're not actually calling `$remove`. In your fix, you're passing  `article` into `$remove`, but `$remove` does not take any arguments. Lastly, creating new `$firebaseObject`s solely for update/delete doesn't make sense. Just use the vanilla Firebase refs.

Comment: And why would it work with the argument then? I am confused because it seems Angular fire has near-identical calls as firebase yet both seem to work. I am trying to understand the purpose of Angular fire in these instances.

Comment: There is no purpose of AngularFire here. It's a bindings library for synchronizing data between Angular and Firebase. All you are doing is deleting data from the remote instance. Since $remove() takes no arguments, passing an argument into $remove() is superfluous.